# VNC black or frozen screen problems

Tags: release-freya

I'm on the latest version of elementary OS with dual monitors using the Nvidia binary drivers (340.96). When I try to VNC in over VPN all I get is a black screen with a cursor. I can move around the cursor but that's it. I'll ssh in and reboot the machine, then I can VNC in.

Additionally, if I'm VNC'd in, then leave the machine idle for say 10 minutes then try to come back the screen freezes and I need to ssh in and reboot the machine, then I re-VNC in.

After searching online for a bit, the only thing I could find that was close was this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/127466/blank-screen-with-vnc-server which talks about trying to VNC in and connecting to the wrong monitor. I'm not sure that's what the issue is here, but that's the best lead I have. Nothing in that post's solution applied to my machine.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.